# Why my image does not save

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I have a simple program with JFrame and Jpanel on it and I want to draw a line on the JPanel and save the result of the drawing to an image. But it completely does not work.

Where was I wrong?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class source {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("TEST");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setVisible(true);
        mainPanel.setSize(800, 600);
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        window.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        window.setSize(800, 600);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
        Graphics g = mainPanel.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 50, 50);

        BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage)mainPanel.createImage(300, 300);
        try {
            System.out.println("Saved");
            ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("filename1.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(source.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("Not saved");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `mainPanel.createImage(300, 300);` That produces a blank image, compatible for displaying on the panel. It is **not** an image of what is currently on the panel. BTW - there is another way to approach this. Create a `BufferedImage` to display in a `JLabel`. Draw on the buffered image and then `repaint()` the label to see the changes. Save that image when needed.

Comment: @AndrewThompson so you want to say that I can`t pick a graphic of a Jpanel, draw in it and then copy the result to a BufferedImage? I can only draw on a BufferedImage and that copy the result to JPanel, yes?

Comment: I don't want to say any such thing. It's just **easier** the way I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use getGraphics(). That is not how you do custom painting.

Instead you need to override the `paintComponent()` method of the JPanel and do your custom painting in that method. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

```
BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage)mainPanel.createImage(300, 300);
```

All that does is create an empty BufferedImage.

You need to paint something on the BufferedImage by using its Graphics object. The basic code is something like:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(theWidth, theHheight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
someComponent.print( g2d );
g2d.dispose();
```

However the above logic will only work when done on a visible GUI. This means you would need to create your frame and add the panel to the frame. Then you would create a "Save Image" button to add to the frame. Then you add an ActionListener to the button. In the listener code you create the BufferedImage and save the image to a file.

Or if you just want to create an image and save it to a file then you just paint directly to the BufferedImage:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(theWidth, theHheight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
g2d.setColor( Color.WHITE );
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, theWidth, theHeight);
g2d.setColor( Color.Black );
g2d.drawLine(...);
g2d.dispose();
```

Comment: If I put my code to paintComponent() will I receive an image of drawing?